# Stack Exchange is not working properly

Tags: support, quality-filter

When I try to post a question, the site says to edit it and to add "what you have tried" and "it's not up to quality standards" and stuff.

But this message keeps coming up when I'm trying to post every single question. This happens when I get every detail right and I can't add any more specific detail.

It still says to add more stuff when I have already have added everything I can.

This is starting to annoy me  - I have been getting this message for my questions for about an hour now.

Comment: The very fact that you were able to post this question implies that it __is__ working properly.

Comment: Given the lack of proper punctuation, correct use of I and complete lack of paragraphs in this post ([first revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/224545/1)), if your other attempts are similar, then the low quality filter is doing its work correctly.

Comment: Could you post that question here in blockquotes so we can see it and give you better feedback?

Comment: Take a look at the edits I have made to your post here. These are syntactical and grammatical changes that we would expect you to have made in the first place.

Comment: the lack of proper punctuation is not the point. the point is when i have got all the details on the question that i can possibly have it still says i am not specific enough still

Comment: A *developer for Stack Exchange* is telling you punctuation, syntax, and grammar are (is?) an issue. It's an issue.

Comment: @user121855 Proper punctuation, or the lack thereof, is as much a quality issue as a bad or unclear question is. We like our content to be good, and a lot is done to ensure that.

Comment: and i am extremely bad at punctuation so have the people that created this site every thought about the people that are bad at it they just not let them post questions that's not fair. its basically banning people from doing stuff because there not good at something

Comment: Sure they have thought it of. And they stop you because of it. So now you know to improve. And as an added bonus, multiple users have now shown you how to improve. So we all win. Good luck.

Comment: Punctuation and Grammar is what separates us from animals (and forums).

Comment: If you edit your original intended question text into the question above (using blockquotes) I'm sure someone will help you edit it into shape. I will if I'm around and see it.

Comment: Feel free to ask your questions on Yahoo Answers. Note that you'll get answers from the kind of people who don't care if they're on a site with quality questions.

Comment: but with yahoo answers there system is stupid you need points to post questions and i have 0 points on it and i can only answer questions that come up every 2 hours because most questions i dont know

Comment: @user121855 Does it even matter if you know about whats being asked? Its *Yahoo answers*; Just post anything.

Comment: @user121855 Does it even matter if you know about whats being asked? Its Yahoo answers; Just post anything. – AsheeshR 1 min ago            what are you talkng about do you even know what i asked

Comment: For what @AsheeshR said, that's the difference between our site and Yahoo Answers (and others). We want a high level of quality in our users and content, so that we can attract experts. If we allow low quality content, then people will care less about the quality of the site, and therefor less quality answers and users.

Comment: @user121855 maybe you can try add the question you want to post here as suggested by others. Also, for the starter, use short and simple sentence. I find it quite difficult to read and understand your comment without proper punctuation.

Comment: just so you know from my point of view im bad at punctuation but i have to go to a place to ask questions i need to know. but my questions keep getting stopped from posting and there's no other place to ask it that's good so you cant just stop someone from trying to learn something just because they bad at something the people that created this site are just being rude

Comment: @user121855 If you are unwilling to use full stops (.), commas (,), capitals at the beginning of a sentence (like in this one^), and capital `I`s, then Yahoo answers is a pretty good alternative. We are trying to *help* you here (users edited this question itself which should tell you something), but can only do so when *you* take the first few steps.

Comment: @user, I beg to differ. From your comments so far, you are the one who's being rude. It also looks like you do not wish to make any effort whatsoever to improve the situation.

Comment: have you every though that i find it difficult to improve my skills for editing it this is the best im probly going to get so you people have to deal with it and not just stop peoples questions from being posted just because of punctuation

Comment: No. We will keep stopping such posts. We expect a certain quality from posts - that includes minimal correct punctuation/grammar and syntax. As others have pointed - if you can't be bothered to correct these minimal issues (start your sentences with capital letters, capitalizing your `I`s, using commas and periods where they belong and breaking up walls of text into paragraphs), then how can we think you would be bothered to post a quality question at all?

Comment: You can't tell me that you cannot write *"Have you every thought that I find it difficult to improve my skills for editing it. This is the best I'm probly going to get. So you people ..."* This does not nearly address all the issues, but certainly you can capitalize properly and use punctuation. Telling me you can't basically just means you're lazy and unwilling to improve.

Comment: and why are people voting this question down it is clear of the point i am trying to make and i cant research anything for my question

Comment: [given this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/224545/1 "original question revision"), I am heavily tempted to edit the title of this question into "Stack Exchange *is* working properly"

Comment: @user121855 To say that we "have to deal with it?"  Yeah, right...

Comment: This does not nearly address all the issues, but certainly you can capitalize properly and use punctuation. Telling me you can't basically just means you're lazy and unwilling to improve                                well people like me have stuff to do and don't have time. not like some people just sitting on the computer editing questions all day

Comment: Yet you're wasting hours of your precious time, trying to shove your crappy questions down the site's throat when with a couple of simple adjustments you could be getting actual help. You're absolutely right, we are the problem, not you .... (yep, that was sarcasm right there)

Comment: You can't tell me that you cannot write "Have you every thought that I find it difficult to improve my skills for editing it. This is the best I'm probly going to get. So you people ..." This does not nearly address all the issues, but certainly you can capitalize properly and use punctuation. Telling me you can't basically just means you're lazy and unwilling to improve. – Bart 5 mins ago         well maby people like me have stuff to do and dont have any spare time not like some people editing questions all day

Comment: lol, OK this is a lost cause. Voting to close now.

Comment: If you can't put in the time for that, than you certainly can't put time into a quality question.

Comment: @user121855 Just saying, people won't give their time to help someone who don't have time to improve him/herself.

Comment: and im not wasting my time you are. if someone just looked into it and fixed the system you wouldn't be wasting my time and you wouldn't be wasting yours

Comment: Yeah. And it's a widespread problem,  too. I applied to study Nuclear Science at MIT and they rejected me just because I failed at grade school math, physics, and chemistry. Those *jerks*

Comment: @Pëkka Yeah, and when I wanted to play footie in the Premier League, they rejected me _just because I'm rubbish at football_. What a world.

Comment: @Pëkka This user honestly believes that he is entitled to freely be bad at communicating without anyone being biased toward them for it.  As if there is some sort of unjust anti-bad-communicator prejudice going on in this world.  This is one of the most pleasantly absurd conversations I've seen in a while.

Comment: @user121855 it is really quite simple and is **not** likely to change - write a clear, concise question with correct punctuation etc, so t could be easily read, then you'll more likely get good answers. Bad punctuation is hard to read, so why would people bother?

Answer (score 14):

It's likely that your questions are being rejected because of punctuation and grammar.

That restriction isn't going to go away.

It's nothing personal - I know very, very bright people who are terrible at punctuation and grammar for some reason. But it makes for a difficult to read question, and most of the time, is accompanied by other quality issues.

To some extent, you may be able to get help fixing your contributions here. I (and many others here) am happy to go over your original question if you edit it into your question above (please use block quotes). Also consider asking family or friends for help - and long term, work on those things. Some level of punctuation and grammar is really super important to get on in the world.

Answer (score 2):

It seems plausible that the main issue you are running into is with the **grammar, punctuation, spelling, and overall syntax** of your posts.  The posts I have seen from you (including the one for this question, before it was edited) have issues that make it difficult to read, as well as unprofessional and of low quality overall.

You should take this not as a personal attack, but as constructive criticism, and view it as a chance to improve.  Proper writing skills are *very important* for a great deal of things.  The main areas of improvement you should consider are use of punctuation for pacing ideas, capitalization of the first letter of sentences and I, use of apostrophes where necessary, and separating out run-on sentences into individual ideas.

As you start to improve in these areas, especially after taking an active effort, I'm certain you will find your posts in much less need of editing by others, and perhaps you yourself can even become an editor.

Comment: I actually find this less readable with all the extra formatting you added.

Comment: @Oded Meh, to each their own.  I'm a big form of highlighting, and it serves me well.

Comment: I find it super-irritating to have to read text with too much emphasis. Just sayin'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *Solid Snake* "Foine, Jeez."